# On the centre of Weyl algebra when char K = p

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Please, I need some clarification about Weyl algebra, in Lemma 3, statment 1 and 2 [Weyl algebra](http://www.math.kochi-u.ac.jp/docky/preprints/dixmier1.pdf):

For any ring $k$, we denote by $A_n(k)$ the Weyl algebra.
$$
A_n(k)=k\left\langle\xi_1, \xi_2, \ldots, x_n, \eta_1, \eta_2, \ldots, \eta_n\right\rangle /\left(\eta_j \xi_i-\xi_i \eta_j-\delta_{i j} ; 1 \leq i, j \leq n\right)
$$

**Lemma 3**. Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p$. We have the following facts.

**(1)** $\xi_i^p, \eta_j^p$ belongs to the center of $A_n(k)$.

**(2)** More precisely, the center $Z_n(k)=Z\left(A_n(k)\right)$ of the ring $A_n(k)$ is given by
$$
Z_n(k)=k\left[\xi_1^p, \ldots, \xi_n^p, \eta_1^p, \ldots, \eta_n^p\right]
$$

To prove this is the centre of weyl algebra.

**My attempt is:** let $n=1$, then: $A_{1}(k)=k [\xi, \eta]$, So the centre of $A_{1}$ according to 2 is
$$
Z(A_1(k))=K \left[\xi^p, \eta^p\right]
$$
to prove this we suppose: $\xi^p$ is central, then: $\left[\xi, \xi^p\right]=p \xi_1^{p-1}=0$

**My question:**
after this step, please, how I can say this element is central? I mean why  $p \xi_1^{p-1}=0$

I would appreciate if you could help.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Also, please try to make questions self-contained. State the theorem and establish the notation.

Comment: *You need to make the question self-contained.*

Comment: For example, you need to define $\xi_i^p$ and $\eta_j^p$, and state exactly what it is you want to prove.

Comment: Also, to get the attention of a user with username `User Name`, type `@UserName`. You can only tag one user per comment though.

Comment: Thank you so much, Shaun.